# Javascript platformer collision detection

Tags: javascript, html

So this question has probably been asked a couple times before, but I can't seem to find a way to make collision detection work properly.

I'm trying to make an HTML canvas/Javascript platformer game. It's on codepen if you'd like to see what it does: https://codepen.io/Arthurvanhoorebeke/pen/zpaZYM

What I'm doing is checking in which tiles/'boxes' the corners of my player are. This means I've got OK detection for blocks above and under the player, but sideways detection is pretty bad.

I know that the checks for bottom collision are what messes the sideways detection up, but I can't seem to fix it.
This is what I've got now:

```
function tileCheck(world){
  var player_topy = Math.ceil(player1.pos[1] / world.squareHeight) || 0;
  var player_bottomy = Math.ceil((player1.pos[1]+player1.height)/world.squareHeight) || 0;
  var player_leftx = Math.floor(player1.pos[0]/world.squareWidth) || 0;
  var player_rightx = Math.floor((player1.pos[0]+player1.width)/world.squareWidth) || 0;

  var topRightBlock = getSquare(world1,player_rightx,player_topy-1); 
  var topLeftBlock = getSquare(world1,player_leftx,player_topy-1);
  var bottomRightBlock = getSquare(world1,player_rightx,player_bottomy-1);
  var bottomLeftBlock = getSquare(world1,player_leftx,player_bottomy-1);
  //checks if blocks are solid
  var topRightSol = world.legend[topRightBlock].solid;
  var topLeftSol = world.legend[topLeftBlock].solid;
  var bottomRightSol = world.legend[bottomRightBlock].solid;
  var bottomLeftSol = world.legend[bottomLeftBlock].solid;

  //This kinda messes up my 'sideways collision detection'.
  if((bottomRightSol && !topRightSol) || (bottomLeftSol && !topLeftSol)){
    player1.pos[1] -= (player1.pos[1]+player1.height) - (player_bottomy-1)*world.squareHeight;
    player1.vel[1] = 0;
    player1.grounded = true;
  }
  else{
    player1.grounded = false;
    }
  if((topLeftSol && !bottomLeftSol) || (topRightSol && !bottomRightSol)){
    player1.pos[1] += player_topy*world.squareHeight - player1.pos[1];
    player1.vel[1] = 0;
  }
  //This doesn't work properly.
  if(topLeftSol && bottomLeftSol){
    player1.vel[0] = 0;
    player1.wallLeft = true;
    player1.pos[0] += (player_leftx+1)*world.squareWidth - player1.pos[0];
  }
  else{player1.wallLeft = false}
  if(topRightSol && bottomRightSol){
    player1.vel[0] = 0;
    player1.wallRight = true;
    player1.pos[0] -= (player1.pos[0]+player1.width) - (player_rightx)*world.squareWidth;
  }
  else{player1.wallRight = false}
}
```

I know the sideways detection is not gonna work when only one corner of the player block hits something else. The problem is that when the player hits a block, its vertical position gets changed by the bottom collision checker (at least I think that's the problem.).

If you want to see the exact problem, try opening the codepen link and jumping around a bit...

Is there a fix for this or do I need to rethink my whole function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to try changing this:

`if((bottomRightSol || !topRightSol) || (bottomLeftSol && !topLeftSol)){`

to this:

`if((bottomRightSol || bottomLeftSol) && (!topRightSol && !topLeftSol)){`

The difference here being that, if I understood your code correctly, you'd now be checking to make sure you're colliding with the ground on at least one corner, and then making sure you're not colliding with anything in the corners. I think this should prevent the player from being moved down when mid-air.

---

Edit following comment:

```
//This kinda messes up my 'sideways collision detection'.
  if((bottomRightSol && !topRightSol) || (bottomLeftSol && !topLeftSol)){
    player1.pos[1] -= (player1.pos[1]+player1.height) - (player_bottomy-1)*world.squareHeight;
    player1.vel[1] = 0;
    player1.grounded = true;
  }
  else{
    player1.grounded = false;
    }
  if((topLeftSol && !bottomLeftSol) || (topRightSol && !bottomRightSol)){
    player1.pos[1] += player_topy*world.squareHeight - player1.pos[1];
    player1.vel[1] = 0;
  }
```

That top `if` statement I've already suggested a fix for. That second one lower down I would change to the following:

`if((topLeftSol || topRightSol) && (!bottomLeftSol && !bottomRightSol)){`

This is basically the same change as above, but now checking for the ceiling. Hope this helps.

As an aside, while I believe these solutions are correct, there's no harm in re-writing the function anyway, as suggested.

Comment: This does fix being moved down. The problem I'm left with is being moved up though... I think I'll just have to redo the whole function

Comment: I've edited the 'ifs', and added a check so that the bottom collision does not do anything when the player is moving up. That seemed to fix the thing enough so that I'll be able to figure out the rest by myself :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Total rethink. With collision detection the idea is to predict a path, and this works for 2d as well as 3d and im suggesting more of a full simulation, then if the path is blocked you must find, most importantly often missed, the point of impact.
So it becomes trivial when using boxes in 2d.
calculate a trajectory vector with X Y components.
Then test each box for collision, if many use instancing detection spheres, simply distance between to check if near for colldet, and achieve an impact point.
The impact vector should then be used as the next position for the character. This allows for sliding over edges bouncing off and rebounding.
Hope I helped. otherwise please specify any errors, your code checks out.

Comment: I've already got the player's velocity in an array, so I could probably use that as a vector, yes? Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll see if I can make this work